# Why $8^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is $1$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, pi, cubics

The question is:

Use DeMoivre’s theorem to find $8^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Express your answer in complex form.

Select one:

a. 2

b. 2, 2 cis (2$\pi$/3), 2 cis (4$\pi$/3)

c. 2, 2 cis ($\pi$/3)

d. 2 cis ($\pi$/3), 2 cis ($\pi$/3)

e. None of these

---

I think that $8^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is $(8+i0)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

And, $r = 8$

And, $8\cos \theta = 8$ and $\theta = 0$.

So, $8^{\frac{1}{3}}\operatorname{cis} 0^\circ = 2\times (1+0)=2$

I just got only $2$. Where and how others $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ come from?

Comment: You've made a lot of typos throughout your question, so it's hard to really be sure what numbers you're working with. Would you mind double-checking them?

Comment: Yes, updated and thanks @EeveeTrainer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could look at it like this:
$$8^{\frac13}=2.1^{\frac13}=2\cdot \text{CiS}\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)$$
Now for different values of $k$, we have different answers: (here  $n$ is $3$)
$$k=1\implies 8^{\frac13}=2\cdot\text{CiS} \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$k=2\implies8^{\frac13}=2\cdot\text{CiS}\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$k=3\implies8^{\frac13}=2\cdot\text{CiS}(2\pi)=2$$

You could read up on [$n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) on Wikipedia to get a better picture

Answer (score 3):

Let $z^3=8$.

Thus, $$(z-2)(z^2+2z+4)=0,$$ which gives
$$\{2,-1+\sqrt3i,-1-\sqrt3i\}$$ or
$$\left\{2(\cos0+i\sin0),2\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}\right), 2\left(\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here,
$$\begin{align*}
8^{1/3} &= (|8|e^{2\pi kj})^\frac{1}{3}, k = 0,1,2\\
               &= |8|^\frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi kj},  k = 0,1,2\\
&= 2 e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi kj},  k = 0,1,2\\
\end{align*}$$

so,for $k=1$,$k=2$ we get $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$

Or take:
$$8^{1/3}=x$$
Then we get,

$$(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=0$$

Then we get our desired roots.

Comment: I think it would be better if you could elaborate a little more on the factorization after your substitution of $8^{\frac13} \to x$

Answer (score 1):

$8^{\frac{1}{3}}$=$2(1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=2,2\omega,2{\omega}^2$

here $\omega$ is cube root of unity