# Why does $-8^{\frac{1}{3}}$ have $2$, $e^{\frac{\pi}{3}}$ and $e^{\frac{5\pi}{3}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Use DeMoivre’s theorem to find  $-8^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Express your answer in complex form.

Select one:

a. –2

b. – 2, 2 cis ($\pi$/3)

c. – 2, 2 cis ($\pi$/3), 2 cis (5$\pi$/3)

d. 2, 2 cis ($\pi$/3), 2 cis (5$\pi$/3)

e. None of these

---

The correct answer is : $2, 2 e^{\pi/3}, 2 e^{5\pi/3}$

My calculation is here:

$r=\sqrt{-8^{2}}=8$

Then,

$= 2\ cis\ \frac{2\pi k}{n}$

If k is $0$,

$= 2\ cis\ 0=2$

If k is $1$,

$= 2\ cis\ \frac{\pi }{3}$

If k is $2$,

$= 2\ cis\ \frac{4\pi }{3}$

Therefore, the results are $2$, $= 2\ cis\ \frac{\pi }{3}$, and $= 2\ cis\ \frac{4\pi }{3}$.

So, why the correct answer is $2$, $2\ cis (\frac{\pi}{3})$, $2\ cis (\frac{5\pi}{3})$?

Comment: Where is the negative sign attached?

Comment: @PacoAdajar The negative sign was lost with $\sqrt{-8^{2}}=8$.  That was an error

Comment: $\sqrt{-8^2} = \pm i\sqrt 8$.  $\sqrt{(-8)^2} = 8$.  But... why are you doing that?....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why $8^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is $1$, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791438/why-8-frac13-is-1-frac2-pi3-and-frac4-pi3)

Answer (score 1):

We normally do exponents before multiplication and the minus sign here is a multiplication.  I think the problem wants

$$-(8^{1/3}) \mbox{ non } (-8)^{1/3}.$$

So work out  $8^{1/3}$ to get

$$2, 2 \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right), 2 \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right).$$

Now multiply by $-1$

$$-2, -2 \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right), -2 \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$

And recall that $-\mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)= \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)$ and $-\mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) = \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right).$  so you have

$$-2, 2 \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right), 2 \mbox{ cis } \left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right).$$

I believe the right answer has $-2$ rather than $2$.

Comment: $-(8^{1/3})$ and $(-8)^{1/3}$ should give the same answers, while $-(4^{1/2})$ and $(-4)^{1/2}$ would not

Comment: @Henry  Because cube root is an odd function while square root is even.

Comment: I know. I was suggesting that your first distinction "$-(8^{1/3}) \mbox{ non } (-8)^{1/3}$" might not make a difference to the right answer including "$-2$ rather than  $2$".

Comment: @Henry  The question wasn't to work the problem, but why the answers differed.

Answer (score 0):

Since $-8=8e^{i({\pi+2n\pi})}$ we have $(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}=2e^{i\frac{\pi+2n\pi}{3}}$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ (and you want the cases when $n=0,1$ and $2$).

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite,

$$-8^{\frac13}=2.(-1)^{\frac13}=2\cdot \text{CiS}\left(\frac{2k\pi + \pi}{3}\right)$$

And on substituting,

$k=0,1 $ and $2$ we get our desired answer

Answer (score 0):

$-8 = 8(-1) = 8\operatorname{cis} (\pi) = 8\operatorname{cis}( (2k+1)\pi)$

So $(-8)^{\frac 13} = \sqrt[3]{8}\operatorname{cis}(\frac {2k+1}3\pi)=$.

$2\operatorname{cis}(\frac \pi 3 + \frac {2k\pi}3); k=0,1,2$

$2\operatorname{cis}(\frac \pi 3), 2\operatorname{cis}(\pi)= 2\cdot (-1)=-2, 2\operatorname{cis}(\frac {5\pi} 3)$

You assumed that we needed $3*\theta = 2k \pi$ and you didn't realize we actually needed $3*\theta = (2k+1)\pi$.

.....

And I don't quite understand we you did $r= \sqrt{(-8)^2} 8$.  Is that the $r$ that "belongs to" $-8$ or to $(-8)^{\frac 13}$?  Either way, I'm not sure what you were doing.

To solve $z^{\frac 1m}$ you need to:

1. Express $z = r\operatorname{cis}({\theta})$.  where $r = |z|$ and $\theta =\operatorname{Arg}(z)= \operatorname{Arg}(\frac z{|z|})$.
2. $z^{\frac 1m} = \sqrt[m]{r}\operatorname{cis}(\frac \theta m + \frac {2k\pi}m)$.

so to do $1$ we have $r = |-8| = 8$ and so $\theta = \operatorname{Arg}(-8)= \operatorname{Arg}\frac{-8}{8} =  \operatorname{Arg}(-1) = \pi$.

I think somehow you assumed our Argument was $0$ and not $\pi$.